# Efficient way to create ordered set of string values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, key-value

I want to create an enum-like set of strings in a way that will also provide me the ability to order them by their ordinal value and NOT by alphabetic value. for example:

"Extremely Low" = 0

"Very Low" = 1

"Low" = 2

"Medium = 3

"High" = 4

and so on.

I know that in Java and C# for example, enum types can have a value besides their ordinal value.

Is there any way to achieve the same goal in Objective-C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the strings for I/O and use an enum for all your computations. For example, define your enum:

```
typedef enum { ExtremelyLow, VeryLow, ... High } Rating;
```

You can use this enum in `switch` statements etc. Now you can use an `NSArray` or just a simple C-array to map from enum literals to strings:

```
NSString *RatingToString[] = { @"Extremely Low", @"Very Low", ..., @"High" };

Rating myRating;
NSString *strMyRating = RatingToString[myRating];
```

Going from the string version to the enum is more involved, you can use the same `RatingToString` array and do appropriate comparisons (case-insensitive maybe, fuzzy etc.). You could also use an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary StringToRating = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: RatingToString[ExtremelyLow], [NSNumber numberWithInt:ExtremelyLow, ..., nil];
```

Now a lookup will do an exact match on your string and return a `Rating` wrapped as an `NSNumber`.

Comment: The dictionary idea look very good. i can make static array like this and it will do exactly as i want - i can read string from file and know its value immediately by calling on the dictionary objectForKey: and pass the string from file as the key

Comment: "NSString *strMyRating = RatingToString[myRating];" You are initializing a `NSString *` with a `char *`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a direct way to do that. However, you can define an Obj-C class like this:

```
@interface EnumLike : NSObject
{
    NSString* title;
    NSInteger value;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger value;

// Something like enum
+ (id)extremelyLow;
+ (id)veryLow;
...
+ (id)high;
};
```

Except working with the **switch** this can do the job. I use similar types from time to time to declare some "enums" for the user since a list of such instances can be binded to an NSArrayController and used in the UI.

Comment: Wow this is brilliate! It is almost exactly what i'm looking for. The only missing piece is to add the option to create one of those "pre defined" elements by supplying a string for the value - like "Very Low" and getting back the appropriate EnumLike object. I need this because i'm reading the data from a file and i need to parse those strings into something i can work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class like Gobra suggested or an array of c structs:

```
typedef struct {
    int                      type;
    NSString                 *desc;
} NXENumToNSString;



NXENumToNSString kNXGMWidgetTypes[] = {
    {1, @""},
    {2, @"imageGallery"},
    {3, @"dotImageGallery"},
    {4, @"video"},
    {5, @"webView"},
    {6, @"image"}
};

NSInteger  
intToStringForArray(NXENumToNSString *buffer, size_t length, NSString *str) 
{
    int result = NSIntegerMin;
    NXENumToNSString *scan, *stop;  
    scan = buffer;
    stop = scan + length;
    while (scan < stop) {
        if ([scan->desc isEqualToString:str]) {
            result = scan->type;
            break;
        }
        scan++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

then you can do something like this:

```
 size_t l = sizeof(kNXGMWidgetTypes) / sizeof(NXENumToNSString);
 NSInteger result = intToStringForArray(kNXGMWidgetTypes, l, str);
```